# Network Trash Can on macOS 10.13 or higher?

Tags: mac, network, finder, server.app, trash

We currently have a Mac that functions as a file server on our network. The files are stored locally on an internal drive array. We would like to setup a Network Trash Can on this machine so when other users access it and delete files, they aren't deleted permanently. Does macOS Server have support for a Network Trash Can? If not, what else would you all recommend?

Thank you,
Mason